# React Router Tabs -- Keep Components Mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, react-router

I have created tabs using React Router, with a different route for each tab. However, I would like to maintain the tab state between tab transitions by keeping the hidden tabs mounted. How do I achieve this? React router remounts each component every time the route switches.

Someone has already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362370/react-router-how-to-achieve-tab-like-navigation), but has not received an answer

Ideally I would find a solution which keeps the tabs which are not displayed mounted after they are hit for the first time

Comment: if you want to maintain `state` for several components you would need a parent component that is not re-mounting or a state manager like `redux`.

Comment: @Sag1v thank you! I would much rather keep track of the component states inside the components themselves, I really just want to leave the components mounted within one session between switching tabs

Comment: i don't think there's a "clean" way of doing it other than the good practice and design pattern of `react` and its tools. maybe you could save it in local storage, but i advice against that. `state` is a memory object that belongs to instance of a `class` (`React.component` class), when you destroy the class you destroy this object. the orthodox approach is to lift the state up to a common parent or save it externally via a state manager like `redux`

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'd be very interested in a solution

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to do a little more digging to confirm this actually works, but reading through React Router docs I found [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/Route-render-methods) about the `Route` component. Using the `component` prop makes the component remount every time the route changes. But using the other render methods, you might be able to achieve what you're looking for. I'd go with `render`, but `children` might work too?

Answer (score 1):

This is the recommended method of routing by react-router-dom-v5 doc over `render`,`children` and `component` prop of `<Route/>`. This way our component gets **re-initialized & re-mounted** everytime path is matched.

```
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
       <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/contact">
       <Contact />
     Route>
    <Route path="/about">
       <About />
    </Route>
 </Switch>
```

As you(Kat) want to maintain the tab state between tab transitions by keeping the hidden tabs mounted.

- you can achieve this by mounting all the tabs at once and then switch between the tabs by using `react-router-dom`'s `pathname`.

```
const { pathname } = useLocation();
{pathname === "/"? <Home/>: null}
{pathname === "/contact"? <Contact/>: null}
{pathname === "/about"? <About/>: null}
```

- This way your component will not get re-initialized and re-mounted everytime path is matched and hence component states will not be disturbed and will be taken care of automatically accross the tabs.
- Here is the working **DEMO**: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-experiment-ilfhq?file=/src/component/Home.js:166-201
- Hope I answered your question.
- Here is the **second solution DEMO** using `CSS`: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-mouted-routes-32dxf?file=/src/App.js